# Как пост в wordpress хранит информацию о метках?

Tags: wordpress, база-данных

В wordpress есть таблица `wp_terms` которая хранит термины. В таблице `wp_term_taxonomy` происходит связывание термина с таксономией, ну и таблица `wp_term_relationships`, которая связывает таксономии с конкретным постом.

В записи есть поле с метками. У меня есть метка `My_Label` в этом поле. То есть я вижу в таблице `wp_term_relationships`, что `object_id` ссылается на `term_taxonomy_id`, все в порядке, так и должно быть. Но после того как я удаляю эту метку при редактировании поста и сохраняю его, я продолжаю видеть эту связь между ними в `wp_term_relationships`, хотя по факту она была удалена, что подтверждается логикой на сайте (он больше не находит этот пост по данной метке).

Так вот вопрос: а где блин она тогда сохраняется то если не в `wp_term_relationships` в которой она всегда присутствует после добавления? Такое ощущение, что где-то стоит какой-то переключатель `on|off`, так как связь продолжает работать, а по логике должна пропасть из `wp_term_relationships`, я не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отбой вопросу, я всю голову себе сломал... Оказалось, что я забыл сменить базу данных на вторую тестовую... Логика описанная мною выше в целом правильная. Именно так они и хранятся, а после удаления метки удаляется и связь из `wp_term_relationships`.